# How to add a value from input and a created element with JS to the list?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I'm building a list in JavaScript ES5, and it says that 'node' something can't  be this or that.

Well, my first real adventure on making the list. But I'm not sure how to figure this out, not sure what's up with the 'node' stuff in the console. I tried node.appendChild, appendNode etc... pretty much everything I could think off.

Here is the CodePen to the code: https://codepen.io/Aurelian/pen/ypKxwL?editors=1010

The JS:

```
       window.onload = function() {

  ///////////////////
  //Variables
  ///////////////////

  //   Variables
  var newTaskInput = document.querySelector('#new-task');
  var addTaskButton = document.querySelector('#add-task');



  var incompleteTasks = document.querySelector('#incomplete-tasks');
  //var completeTasks = document.querySelector('#complete-tasks');

  function createNewTaskElement(userValue) {
    var listItem = document.createElement('li');
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    var editInput = document.createElement('input');
    var editButton = document.createElement('button');
    var deleteButton = document.createElement('button');

    label.innerHTML = userValue;
    editInput.type = "text";
    editButton.className = "edit";
    deleteButton.className = "delete";

    // Insert that to the li
    listItem.appendChild(label);
    listItem.appendChild(editInput);
    listItem.appendChild(editButton);
    listItem.appendChild(deleteButton);

    return listItem;;
  }


  // Function
  function addNewTask() {

    incompleteTasks.push(createNewTaskElement);
  }

  //function deleteTask () {
    // this.pop;
  //}

  //Events
  addTaskButton.addEventListener('click', addNewTask);

}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">


<div class="">
  <label for="new-task">Add Item</label>
  <input id="new-task" type="text">
  <button id="add-task">Add</button>
</div>

<div>
  <h3>Todo List</h3>
  <ul id="incomplete-tasks">
        <li>
          <label>Pay Bills</label>
          <input type="text">
          <button class="edit">Edit</button>
          <button class="delete">Delete</button>
        </li>
  </ul>
</div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling `createNewTaskElement` as a function and `incompleteTasks` is not an array its a DOM object so no `push` method is available.

`incompleteTasks.push(createNewTaskElement);`

should be

`incompleteTasks.appendChild(createNewTaskElement());`

Find [here in codepen](https://codepen.io/Memolition/pen/MrVPGJ) the updated code.

Comment: Right! So everytime that I want to use function, I need to use the () right?

And push works only on push. Okay. That makes sense.

Comment: Do you know perhaps why can't I add the .value? I did append it to the element, but I can't get it and add it. It's undefined.

Comment: @AurelianSpodarec updated my answer for you to have an example on using the `value` property. Also notice that I changed your `input` id as it was the same as your submit button.

Comment: @AurelianSpodarec yes, every time you need to call a function use `([any arguments, comma-separeted])`

Comment: I was kinda close xd kinda but yeah, well, after I updated my code since that one is old but still good. Really helps! That works! Thanks :) I feel I'm learning a lot of JS by doing daily features :D

Comment: One second, I have it right however, but I put in a variable there that has the same code you put, how come this doesn't work? - https://codepen.io/Aurelian/pen/ypKxwL

Comment: @AurelianSpodarec Took me a second. You are defining `newTaskInput` once at the beginning of the excecution. You need to define it every time your form is submitted. [Find it updated here](https://codepen.io/Memolition/pen/XVExGV?editors=1010#0)

Comment: Hmmm, not sure why we can't pass that code from the top where the variables are declared : p Do you have anything or know a piece of documentation worth reading for this perhaps? 

I did it this way - https://codepen.io/Aurelian/pen/ypKxwL

It seems outside the function I can't change it? Hmm. Scope. Not sure :D 

I guess with delete is till be to pop this item off, but then it's not an array, so remove the child or something :D Perhaps I need to crete an array? 

var listIncomplete = array[]; or something? that way the pop and push will work right so I just need to push it ther nd app

Comment: It is entirely Scopes, at the beginning your variable is getting initialized with a the value `#new-task` has when the script is first excecuted (which would be empty `""`).

Comment: To remove it you would add an `eventListener` to the `document` [Here the updated example with remove event listener](https://codepen.io/Memolition/pen/RxMqow)

Comment: How about with this example here? - https://codepen.io/Aurelian/pen/ypKxwL?editors=1010

 It deletes the first button, but the added buttons won't get removed

Comment: That's the same behavior as with the initialization of the `taskInput` earlier, this event listener is added to the existent button, but won't track any further elements because the event was initialized before the elements existed. That's why you add the `click` event listener to the document and validate your DOM attributes (in this case `className`.

Comment: What about binding the event so what I did should work if I somehow bind it, right? Somehow : p